# What code to create a video generating software?

Tags: python

I've co-founded a startup recently and part of our product requires us to create videos with text, images, and Gifs. We're using an external tool to generate these videos for the moment but we will need to create our own internal tool eventually. 
My question is : 
Is it really complex to create an app (intern use only) like this one: https://mojo.video/ ?
And what code would be best to develop this app?

Thank you very much (and sorry if I sound a bit dum, I'm not familiar with coding at all...)

Alice

Comment: You can make animations (gif or mov, for example) easily by scripting imagemagick. The script can be called from PHP exec() or you can script in PHP Imagick. An interface can be done in PHP. Or you can make the interface with Python and OpenCV. I have scripted simple animations this way including some with transitions. You can see some examples at http://fmwconcepts.com/imagemagick. See fxtransitions, transitions, sinescrollimage, scalescroll, sinescrolltext, typewriter, zoomrotatetext.

Answer (score 0):

In short, it varies massively depending on your goals, but probably lands somewhere on the "very hard" end of the spectrum.

If all you're looking to do is superimpose text on images in a web page, that's actually reasonably easy -- look into `absolute` positioning (controlling placement) where the text has a higher `z-index` than (its height on page, putting it *above*) the image.

Another good option for basic manipulation of images (still or moving, although video might be harder, I don't know) is the excellent command-line utility `ImageMagick`. You could use that to take an input image, then bake-in text to the output image.

However, if you're looking to create something more like a full-featured video editor (Adobe Premiere, Final Cut Pro, Avid, etc.), the answer is that it will be very, very hard. An honest-to-goodness NLE probably requires an engineering staff of tens (if not hundreds) of people who work for years. Creating a simple utility to superimpose text on images for an internal website would take a single engineer a few days to few weeks. Depending on your specific goals, the difficulty could be anywhere between these two extremes.

---

A word of advice: whoever is your software engineer for this task, strive for dialogue on the difficulty of different approaches/objectives. Some things will be trivially easy to code, while others will be crushingly hard. From the outside though, it can be hard to tell the difference between what objectives will be which of the two extremes. If you can avoid having exacting requirements at the start of the project and engage in a dialogue about priorities and options, you might be able to get something that can satisfy all parties while not being a huge resource sink.